# Inequality Question

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ be a bounded open set with diam$(\Omega) \leq R.$ Let $d_1 = \sup_{x \in \Omega}(\xi \cdot x)$ and $d_2 = \inf_{x \in \Omega}(\xi \cdot x)$ for some $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n.$ How would I show that $\sup_{\Omega}(e^{d_1-d_2}-e^{x \cdot \xi-d_2}) \leq e^{|\xi|R}?$

What I've done so far. Clearly $x \cdot \xi-d_2 \geq0 \implies - e^{x \cdot \xi-d_2} \leq -1.$ Not sure about this part but if the diam$(\Omega) \leq R$, does this imply that $d_1-d_2 \leq R$, so $\sup_{\Omega}(e^{d_1-d_2}-e^{x \cdot \xi-d_2}) \leq e^{R}-1.$ Any help/hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d_1-d_2 \leq |\xi|R$ because $|\xi.x-\xi.y|\leq |\xi|diam (\Omega)$ for all $x,y \in \Omega$. Hence, $e^{d_1-d_2}-e^{x.\xi-d_2}\leq e^{d_1-d_2} \leq e^{|\xi|R}$.